# Swift Sqlite3 add table only once

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

i'm new to swift programing language and i learned how to creat a new Table with this code

```
if let _ = SD.createTable("HouseArray", withColumnNamesAndTypes: ["House" : .StringVal]){
} else {
    for each in HouseArray{
        SD.executeChange("INSERT INTO HouseArray (House) VALUES ('\(each)')")
    }
}
```

the thing i don't understand is, for every user downloading my app a new table should be created and that works fine,
since the Create() of a table is in ViewDidLoad() it get called every time I'm in that view controller Nothing happens since the table already exist and only a command line outputs "table already exist"
is there any why to avoid calling Create() every time and make a table once in an app life time?
and i need to populate the table with objects from arrays since its empty
there for the Insert into query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using NSUserDefaults, in which you can permanently store data. Before you try create your table, check if this is the first time a app is opened like this:

```
//put this inside viewDidLoad (or wherever you create your Table)
if !NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("FirstTimeLauched") {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "FirstTimeLauched")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    create() // do your table creating code here.
}
```

Comment: Your solution was great ! yet the false in second line should be changed to True, for it not to go in next time